# httpsCallable is not a function when calling a Firebase function

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to implement a role-based authentication using Firebase auth and Firebase functions. Right now I have a registration form that is working as supposed and now I'm trying to add a form that you submit an email that calls the Firebase function that will attach a custom claim to a user. I already added my function to Firebase via the terminal and I'm calling functions on my project but whenever I submit the form with the email I get a `httpsCallable is not a function` error.

Here are my files:

**index.js** inside functions folder

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.addAdminRole = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  //get user and add custom claim (admin)
  return admin
    .auth()
    .getUserByEmail(data.email)
    .then(user => {
      return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {
        admin: true
      });
    })
    .then(() => {
      return {
        message: `Success! ${data.email} has been made admin`
      };
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return err;
    });
});
```

My **firebaseInit.js** config file where I call everything firebase related

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "@firebase/functions";
import firebaseConfig from "./firebaseConfig";
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const fc = firebase.functions();
export const db = firebase.firestore();
export const fv = firebase.firestore.FieldValue;

export default firebaseApp.firestore();
```

And my **Vue** component where the form is

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <h3>Welcome to Site</h3>

    <h3>Add user to admin</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <form @submit.prevent="addAdmin()" class="col s12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="email" type="email" class="validate" v-model="email" />
            <label for="email">Email</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
        <router-link to="/members" class="btn grey">Cancel</router-link>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import fc from "../data/firebaseInit";
export default {
  name: "home",
  data() {
    return {
      email: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addAdmin() {
      const addAdminRole = fc.httpsCallable("addAdminRole");
      addAdminRole(this.email).then(result => {
        console.log(result);
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Can someone shed a light on why I'm getting this error? Am I forgetting to import something firebase related?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that by doing

```
export const fc = firebase.functions();
export const db = firebase.firestore();
export const fv = firebase.firestore.FieldValue;

export default firebaseApp.firestore();
```

in your `firebaseInit.js` file, you aren't exporting `fc` (nor `fv` by the way)

The following should work

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/functions";   // <-- Note that the @ was removed
import firebaseConfig from "./firebaseConfig";
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const fc = firebase.functions();
const db = firebase.firestore();
const fv = firebase.firestore.FieldValue;

export { fc, db, fv };
```

Then, in your component you do:

```
import {fc, db, fv} from "../data/firebaseInit";

//....
```

Or the following it you only need `fc` and `db`, for example:

```
import {fc, db} from "../data/firebaseInit";

//....
```

Comment: the export {fc, db, fv} fixed it, but I also had to remove the export from the const fc, db, fv. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Oh yeah! I hadn't notice that there were some exports in front of those lines!! :-)

Comment: ERROR:    firebaseApp  is initialised but never used.

Comment: @mazakpe Please ask a question with all  the details: your code and the error message.

Answer (score 1):

I could solve this problem in a different way. I am working with Vue 2.6. In my component I just need:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
const functions = firebase.functions();
var addMessage = functions.httpsCallable("addMessage");
```

In my main.js file I have:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import vuetify from "./plugins/vuetify";
import router from "./router";
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/functions";
import store from "./store";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = true;

Vue.prototype.$firebase = firebase;

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {

};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

let app;

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (!app) {
    app = new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    render: h => h(App)
  }).$mount("#app");
}
```

And in the dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
   "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "firebase": "^8.0.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.13.2",
    ...
 }
```

This is basically the instructions of the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable  applied to Vue.js